# Как правильно задать ресурсы зависящие от dpi и размера экрана в дешёвых смартфонах/планшетах?

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-style

Доброго!
Пытаюсь заставить корректно отображать ресурсы на экранах дешёвых смартфонов/планшетов.
**Проблема такова:** есть, к примеру, тестовый планшет с разрешением `1024х600` с `170dpi`, размер `7'`. При запуске приложения андроид использует ресурсы для `hdpi`. На втором, с `1024х768` с `163 dpi`, размер `7.85'`, использует mdpi. На первом планшете всё значки огромны, текст тоже, на втором - всё идеально.
Так же запускал кучу эмуляторов с различными параметрами, ситуация аналогична, маленькое разрешение и высокий dpi - всё огромное. Сначала думал создать папки ресурсов и с указанными разрешениями и dpi, но потом понял, что картина не меняется, т.к. есть же и `320dpi` c относительно небольшим разрешением. Так же есть toolbar, drawerLayout - и тут такая же ситуация, они занимают просто 50% рабочего пространства.
**Вопрос:** Как это делается правильно в таких случаях?

Comment: 170dpi и hdpi? Кажется, что-то пошло не так. Мне казалось, что порог hdpi около 200.

Comment: я тоже так пологал, но всё обстоит именно так, я проверял, менял рисунок именно для этого разрешения и он был там